# Warning : 'g_hash_table_iter_next from incompatible pointer type' with HashTagIter in Vala

Tags: warnings, hashtable, vala

The following code compile but raise warnings. So I would like to understand what happen really to correct it (I don't like the idea to have warnings at compilation) :

```
// Display couples
// words is a HashTable<string, int> with words and the number of matches in a text
var iter = HashTableIter<string, int>( words );
string key;
int val;
while ( iter.next( out key, out val ) == true )     // TODO Look what 'out' is for
{
    stdout.printf( "%s : %d\n", key, val );
}
```

The warnings :

```
/Users/horizon/Projets/voynich/src/Voynich.vala.c:534: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘g_hash_table_iter_next’ from incompatible pointer type
/Users/horizon/Projets/voynich/src/Voynich.vala.c:534: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘g_hash_table_iter_next’ from incompatible pointer type
/Users/horizon/Projets/voynich/src/Voynich.vala.c:538: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

As I said, the code compile and it works well (no segfault or anything else for the moment).

How can I fix this warning ?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: By the way, `out` is to signify a parameter that you pass to a function uninitialized. The function initializes it for you with some output value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore CC warnings, you can't fix them. You only want to look at Vala warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately this is also what I've found. You can silence them by passing `-w` to your gcc invocation.

Comment: @ptomato How do you do that ? My makefile looks like this : https://bitbucket.org/martindamien/akita/src/ceee8a3b0ceb/makefile

Comment: add `-X -w` to your `CFLAGS` variable.